# Keep the last n number of Docker images in the Registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

In my private Docker registry, I have more than 200 images and the count keeps on increasing. I want to keep only the last 20 images built all the time. In a lot of private Docker registries, they are offering the lifecycle policies.
If there is no lifecycle policy exists and we have to remove it using script, how can we do that?

**Scenario 1:** I have 200 images. When I run the script, I want to keep last 20 images built.

**Scenario 2:** I have 20 images alone. Now, I am pushing an image now. Then, the 20th old image has to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terms of the steps for the logic for a bash script,

1. Login to your docker registry.
2. Find all Images stored in your registry, and add to an array.
3. Count the amount of elements in your array, and store this into a variable, for example `numberOfImages`.
4. If the `numberOfImages` variable is less then or equals to 20, then do not delete any images. If your count is more than 20 then whatever the `numberOfImages` variable is, -20 from this, and store in the `howManyImagesToDelete` variable. So the latest 20 images still remain and will not be deleted.
5. With your array, start at the end of the array, another counter, for example `i` is created with a while loop, and the `howManyImagesToDelete` variable being used when deleting, the oldest image is deleted first. At the end of the while loop you would +1 on the `i` variable. you would check if this matches with the `howManyImagesToDelete` variable. if this is equal, then to break out of the while loop. and exit the script.